# Unexpected value 'MatSnackBar' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular-material

I wanted to make use of MatSnackBar for displaying notifications on event completion. I imported MatSnackBar in my app module and below is my app.module.ts

```
...
import { MatSnackBar,
    MatSnackBarConfig, ...
} from '@angular/material';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig, ...],
    providers: [...],
    bootstrap: [...],
    entryComponents: [...]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Below is my package.json:

```
{
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.56",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "d3": "^4.10.0",
    "ng-http-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-handsontable": "^1.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
}
```

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'MatSnackBar' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at eval (compiler.js:15206)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15189)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34226)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34187)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34081)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:230)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5573)
    at eval (main.ts:11)
```

I'm using angular material 5.0.0, do I need to use some other version to make use of MatSnackBar?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to import

```
import { MatSnackBarModule } from "@angular/material";
```

and add it under imports

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule,
    ],
    providers: [

    ],
})
```

refer the **[`issue`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7409)**

Comment: Yea, my bad. After adding this import, its working fine, thanks a lot!

Comment: `MatSnackBarModule` is the correct import. NOT `MatSnackBar`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is **what worked for me:**
(before I had import errors like `File 'angular/app/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

1. **Import `MatSnackBarModule`** in `app.module.ts`:

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar'; // <= import the module: MatSnackBarMODULE

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [ 
    ],

    imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule,                                           // <= add it to import list
    ],
   ```

2. And **where using it**, for example in `app.component.ts`:

   ```
   import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar'; // <= ⚠️ import the class with path 'material/SNACK-BAR'

   // […] 

   export class AppComponent {

     constructor( private _snackbar: MatSnackBar ) {     // <= add it to constructor
     }

     // Use it the way you like it
     fooBar() {

         const snack = this._snackbar.open('Hello', 'Action');
         snack
           .onAction()
           .subscribe(() => {
             // Action...
           });
      }        
   }
   ```

[image: logo StackBlitz]

3. **Demo** on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rqjukw?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts)!

Answer (score 0):

import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";

npm i @material/snackbar